# Python XML to csv

Tags: python, csv, xml-parsing

I am learning Python right now on version 2.6.4 
The first thing I am trying to do is trying to parse only the value of an attribute (orderno) and print those out. 
Secondly I am trying to parse through the XML and find a value of an attribute like 10238 from attribut "orderno", but print out the whole item as a csv line like "10238,1,Hasselblad 501 CM body,2355" 
Any pointers on how to do it?

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root:
    first = item.find('orderno').text
    print first
```

Data:

```
<item> 
<orderno>10238</orderno>
<count>1</count>
<name>Hasselblad 501 CM body</name> 
<price>2355</price>
</item> 
<item> 
<orderno>20032</orderno>
<count>1</count>
<name>Carl Zeiss Planar Lens CB 2.8/80 mm</name>
<price>1233</price>
</item> 
<item>
<orderno>30212</orderno>
<count>1</count>
<name>Roll Film 120 Magazine A12</name>
<price>917</price>
</item>
```

Comment: It would be easier if the data had `<items>` tag

Comment: that was just an example. I edited the sample.xml.

Comment: um, if this is python then it's in serious need of code indentation, current one just confuses me

Comment: Your xml didn't change doesn't affect my comment. Regardless, you have no logic to find every `item` tag. Please try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to iterate through all subelements.
Here I've iterated through the sub items through list comprehension and joined the list with comma!

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root:
    print ','.join([sub_item.text for sub_item in item])
```

Sample Output:

```
10238,1,Hasselblad 501 CM body,2355
20032,1,Carl Zeiss Planar Lens CB 2.8/80 mm,1233
30212,1,Roll Film 120 Magazine A12,917
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works perfectly!